# Is it true that MySql database has some limitation?

Tags: php, mysql, record, solution

Is it true that MySql database has some limitation that can cause problem when a table is filled with over 200,000 records?   Whether the question is true ? if yes What will be the solution for that ?

Comment: MySQL can handle tables way over a million in a timely fashion

Comment: @Jansha From where did you hear that? Who said that any such limitation exists?

Comment: My Client has asked me. SO only @SimonAndréForsberg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As alfasin said, there is no 200,000 fixed limit.

However there are limits based on available disk space and largest individual file size; both those depend on the MySQL storage engine you are using (single file / multiple files) and the size of the row multiplied by the number of rows. You'll need to work out the limit based on your OS - you really, really need a HUGE application to reach those limits, though, and if you do get there, you'll have other things to worry about :)

You will also get performance limits if you don't index tables correctly (or have too many indexes); again, no fixed limits and you'll just notice performance dive for some queries.

You can force a table to have limits with MAX ROWS: this is a guide that tells the storage engine how to optimise itself.

But for the purposes of your analysis, you can put millions and millions of rows in a table.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is NO. it has no 200K limitation.

Comment: @Jan `TEXT` type like `BLOB` could be huge - so is `mediumtext`. This is a specific example for which the performance decreased when the table contained more than 200K records - you should not jump into conclusions based on one specific case.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such limitation in MySQL.
See for more info: [MySQL Restrictions and Limitations](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=mysql%20limitations%20&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CE0QFjAA&url=http://downloads.mysql.com/docs/mysql-reslimits-excerpt-5.1-en.pdf&ei=AYEsUMAxiPmtB5LMgZAJ&usg=AFQjCNEyloMBMQFL2GNAUazQDJJJR1PgRw&cad=rja)
And also [MySQL limitations](http://searchsystemschannel.techtarget.com/feature/MySQL-limitations).

Answer (score 1):

The effective maximum table size for MySQL databases is usually determined by operating system constraints on file sizes, not by MySQL internal limits.

Refer this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48633/maximum-table-size-for-a-mysql-database)