# In MySQL Database, which choice is better? Single huge table, or multiple smaller tables

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am creating a huge database.
Currently it have more than 250mb data with 1,500,000+ row.
On next stage on those every row, i will have avg 10+ data.
So, estimates around 2.5GB data in the database.
If i create multiple tables (around 15 to 25) and save data on those tables,
I would have to write complex code (php) to get output.
But if i create single table of 2.5+ gb, most likely it will slow down the process.
Which is better way to do?

Size of data (2.5gb) is estimated/example. please let me know what you think!

Comment: A single "huge" table.  Investigate indexes and partitioning on ways to optimize your queries.

Comment: Why do you think anything will slow down? Why is 2.5 GB the magic number at which point this will happen? Have you actually tried to prove that there *are* performance issues? (FYI, there are *muuuuuch* larger MySQL databases out there running just fine.)

Comment: See [Maximum table size for a MySQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48633/maximum-table-size-for-a-mysql-database)

Comment: @deceze, 2.5gb is not a magic number. i didn't work with any huge database yet. this is my work. while i was inputting data, database response was slow after database become 700mb. that's why i asked. thanks for you information.

Comment: Have you added proper *indices* to your table? Without indices, yes, it'll probably slow down very soon. With indices and properly optimised queries, the database will scale far beyond 2.5 GB.

Comment: @Henrik, after reading the first comment, my project is like a Lilliput compare to that project! thanks for the link.

Comment: @deceze, i know about indexing database. but as not experienced, would you please elaborate or give me some suggestion, to use indices/indexing properly? in database, i am trying to replace "common contents" with id numbers in many different places. and sorry about my bad English, if i do any mistake.

Comment: As a very rough rule of thumb: any column that you're using in a `WHERE` clause should have an index. That allows the database to quickly filter the result set down just by looking at the index. If you don't have an index, it needs to actually read through all 2.5 GB. In practice properly using indices is more complex; use a lot of `EXPLAIN` queries to figure out why a particular query is slow whether an index may help.