# Associating a database table row with Users based on their profile

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, laravel

First of all, I'm sorry if the title isn't really descriptive. I couldn't find another way to put it.

In my application I have the concept of coupons which the user receives based on the coupon's creator criteria. The criterias can be:

1. Tags - a user subscribes to tags (for example tag A and tag B) and when the creator's published a tag he can choose tags for the coupons and if the user has subscribed to the tags the coupon has, he gets them. For that task I have `tags`, `users`, `coupons`, `coupon_tag` and `tag_user` tables with the expected foreign keys for that. **this feature is already implemented.**
2. User's profile - the coupon's creator can decide that he can send the coupon to all users who are of age 25+, live in a certain city, married etc. this data is stored in `profiles` and `addresses` table. The `profiles` table has `user_id` and `address_id`. Now I was wondering how can I implement such a thing? The only idea I had is when the coupon is being created, query the database and fetch all users who match those criterias and then use an insert query for each user. This will require a `coupon_user` table. The downside is that in case that there are 40k users who matches those criteria, I will end up doing 40k(!) insert queries to that table! Not to mention what if there are 100 coupons created each day. It can make the `coupon_user` table grow by millions each day and I'm afraid it will make the application stuck. **this feature isn't implemented as I'm not sure how to do so.**
3. User's purchase data - in my application I have an access to the user's purchase data (an access to his receipts) and a coupon's creator can also decide to send a coupon to every user who has purchased at his store in the last month, or who has purchased in his store and spent more than 50$ in the last 2 months etc. I believe this is somewhat similar to number 2 but I thought it was worth mentioning. **this feature isn't implemented as I don't really know how to do that.**

So basically what I want to do is to make options 2 and 3 possible. I currently have no good solution for that other than the one suggested in option 2.

I have never implemented such a thing and I would like to get your opinions about that. Feel free to suggest any kind of solution which may or may not involve more tables.

Comment: how is the user going to know that they have recieved an coupon?

Comment: If you are comfortable you can potentially use NoSQL database to solve this problem easily

Comment: @MarkNg they log in and they can visit their coupons area and see if there is something new. Alternatively I can store the last login date and when they login see if there is a new coupon for that user since that date and show them a notification.

Comment: @HarshalBulsara I have no experience with NoSQL. I wouldn't mind start reading about it and see if it fits my needs for this application more than the current MySQL database. If possible I would like to know what your solution is but I won't mark it as correct answer before I read more about NoSQL and ensure it fits my needs and easy to learn (since the deadline is approaching)

Comment: then consider placing the crietria to recieve the coupon on the coupon table itself based on user profile, so u will only have 1 entries in the coupon table, pass the arguments when the user log in and only fetch coupon where those criterias are matched

Comment: It sounds like you need to use a joining table that contains the user_id and coupon_id. It could be easily queried to get the users the coupon was sent to, and the coupons a user has received. Table size is another consideration. See this post for more on large mysql tables http://stackoverflow.com/a/4255302/5509627

Comment: @MarkNg I had that in my mind too but it seemed much much more complicated. I guess this solution means I will need a `criterias` table with `coupon_id` column and add all of the criterias for a coupon there. Then I will need to somehow gather the user's data and try to query the DB based on that. It sounds much easier in theory but how can I actually do so? What in case of when I want to send the coupon based on the purchasing data? I'm just clueless as of how to implement that

Comment: @tristan I'm not sure I understood what your suggested? It sounds like what I suggested in option 2?

Comment: #2 creating a join table is the correct approach because it gives you complete control over which coupons a user can see. Right now you have 2 sources - tags and creators sending coupons - but maybe there will be more in the future. You can delete (or archive) coupons they've seen (or that are expired) to keep the table size small. I would consider moving to Redshift since it's sql compatible and built to scale

Comment: @FuzzyTree so you are basically saying that what I suggested at option 2 is the way to go about it and make sure we run some table cleanups sometimes?