# MySQL Performance with .NET Core

Tags: mysql, .net-core

I want to use MySQL with .NET Core for a large website. How reliable is MySQL in terms of speed and performance? Will the performance remain the same with a large number of data growth?

Comment: Define `large number of data growth` and what it's worth to you. **Including management costs**. MySQL doesn't have the multi-GB/TB data management features found in commercial databases, like real physical backups, transparent table partitioning, compression, columnstore indexes. Unless you pay for the Enterprise version to get *some* of them. It doesn't have as smart a query analyzer as the commercial databases either. How many developers could you pay with the license you'd pay for eg SQL Server though? How much does a DBA salary cost? MySQL needs a lot more baby-sitting than eg SQL Server

Comment: 1M rows is small data these days. Every application uses an HTML front end, so everything is a web site. The specific context matters. Does the site need to do a lot of reporting? Is it a commerce site with lots of cross-references? A mainly CRUD web app? A mainly read-only CMS? Each of these has different requirements. MySQL is weak in reporting features like columnstores, compression, cubes. It's cheap though. And if you use a managed (not hosted, managed) instance from one of the big cloud vendors, a lot of admin work is taken care of.

Comment: Then it's a matter of expertise - does your company or your clients have experienced DBAs? For which database?

Comment: My database will have more cross-references, lots of CRUD operations, lots of complex Reporting, my ultimate goal is once data grows, the performance should not suffer...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is MySql good for large databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806290/is-mysql-good-for-large-databases)

Comment: "large" -- Millions of rows and hundreds of queries per second?  Or Billions and thousands?  Give us some specifics; we will give you some answers.