# Is it good to use Mysql for very large database application

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am starting a project for analytics platform using php(just like [kissmetrics](https://www.kissmetrics.com/) , [Appanie](http://www.appannie.com/)) for our product.

So daily our database will get updated with tons of data . Using this data display reports to the users(there are so many reports for single user).

I was wondering whether the MySQL is capable for handling these many tasks.  If mysql is not able to handle this, please suggest and alternate database for this.

Comment: don't think as MySQL is free software so,it is less capable.

Comment: you need to provide additional data like the size of data to be processed each day, the process will include updates,deletes etc

Comment: It depends on the amount of data, amount fo queries, how you build the databse, use indexes, the design of the database... 10 lines in a database can be fetched very slow if sone incorrect :)

Comment: Not exactly what SOF is made for, but mysql can handle lots of data. As you are planning some kind of datawarehouse, you should consider the basic principles of this. The underlying engine is dependent on so many things... Clustering, Hadoop, NoSQL - you got tons of possibilities to solve this...

Comment: you can use `mongo db`

Comment: @Stephan size of the data depends on the users who are going to use our application. Our application(multiple products) will have multiple events so when each user going through our product a record is adding to our database . So the database can be grow enormously. So the basic operation will be insert and select statment.

Comment: @aneesh : mysql can handle this kind of load with the proper architecture for ex : i manage a mysql db that processes billions of entries per day but we have a distributed system on app level also mysql is tuned to our needs

Comment: thanks @Stephan. I am much familar with  mysql database and most of the applications I have developed by using mysql only. But this time I got little confused after googling. that's why I thought of discussing here. What is suggestion about using http://hbase.apache.org/index.html (Hbase). Right now I am planning for standalone system.

Comment: @aneesh hbase is very good at crunching huge amounts of data but if you need a real-time process then i do not think its suitable..

Comment: ok thanks @Stephan will move with mysql

Answer (score 1):

Mysql can handle large data. You can use it. Make sure you implement proper indexing on tables for faster data retrieval. We have successfully used mysql for lakhs of records in a table. Only important part is careful designing of database.

MySQL is capable. Alternate can be postgresql.

Comment: thanks @COG IT Solutions. I will check  postgresql

Comment: Indexes will speed up your reports, but can actually decrease the insertion speed of data. If you have many modifications and only, say, daily reporting, you may be better off without indexes. Indexes aren't always the answer, especially in a more specialized logging-and-reporting environment.

Answer (score 1):

The physical database size doesn't matter. The number of records don't matter.

In my experience the biggest problem that you are going to run in to is not size, but the number of queries you can handle at a time. Most likely you are going to have to move to a master/slave configuration so that the read queries can run against the slaves and the write queries run against the master. However if you are not ready for this yet, you can always tweak your indexes for the queries you are running to speed up the response times. Also there is a lot of tweaking you can do to the network stack and kernal in Linux that will help.

for more details go to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276/how-big-can-a-mysql-database-get-before-performance-starts-to-degrade)

also this data is orignaly taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276/how-big-can-a-mysql-database-get-before-performance-starts-to-degrade)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is not very suitable for this. It has a quite inefficient query cache that is almost entirely flushed as soon as you edit any data in any of the tables used in the query. So when you do many updates, like you describe, querying will seriously slow down. 
That said, for reports you may get away with a bit slower performance than for Web pages, for which MySQL is regularly used, so it might just work.

Many other databases, like Oracle and MS SQL Server are quite more solid, but also cost quite a lot more.

Anyway, it would be wise to make your application as undependent from the database as possible. Make sure you make a good database abstraction layer and don't use many (or any) triggers and stored procedures. That will help you switch databases if you later decide you need to.

Comment: This is a serious problem but could be solved as most reports are based on data that has been processed and not the raw data. Optimizing application structure and logic can avoid a lot of database access and corresponding issues.

Comment: @SvenSchneider You're right, and there are always ways to work around it, but it's a serious bottleneck I've encountered when working with MySQL, so at least it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: Indeed, this should be kept in mind as a switch later will be difficult.