# How to have a version control in django?

Tags: database, django, version-control, orm, django-models

I have Django webapp with different content (e.g. Posts, Threads, comments) and I want to keep track of their history. So I'm trying to create a "version-control" for "content". This is how I'm doing it (skip to the end for the question):

I have a model `Create_Content` which represents an action: has an actor (`editor`), a set of modifications (`edition`), a timestamp, and the content it acts on:

```
class Create_Content(models.Model):
    editor = models.ForeignKey('User')
    edition = models.TextField() # pickled dictionary
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.ForeignKey('Content')
```

which is saved exactly once because history cannot be changed.

I define content has:

```
class Content(models.Model):
    last_edit = models.ForeignKey(Create_Content, related_name='content_last_id')
    first_edit = models.ForeignKey(Create_Content, related_name='content_first_id')

    def author(self):
        return self.first_edit.editor
```

where `last_edit` is the last action performed it, and `first_edition` I use to get the initial author of the content.

All the actual content of the webapp is implemented by derived models of Content, which are created/edited by derived models of `Create_Content`. For instance,

```
class Comment(Content):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="comment_set")
    body = models.TextField()
```

is created during the save of `Create_Comment(Create_Content)` (in fact all subclasses of `Create_Content` are proxies).

For instance, user editions are instances of a subclass of `Create_Content` (e.g. `Edit_Comment(Create_Content)`) which, during `save()`, makes `last_edit` to point onto `self` and updates the actual content (e.g. `Edit_Comment.body`).

In the end I'm doing a simplified version of Git for a database:

- `Create_Content` are commits (which store the complete state in `self.edition`).
- `Content` is a specific branch+working directory (`last_edit` being the pointer),
- A user edition moves the branch forward and changes the `Content`'s to the new content (e.g. `body` of the `Comment`).

### Brief ending

What I realized is that every user action will have an entry in the table of `Create_Content`.

My question are:

how bad is this to happen? I mean, this table can be pretty big, and all actions will be hitting it.

I think my approach is "clean", but I'm pretty sure I'm re-inventing the wheel. What is this specific wheel?

Comment: How about Django-reversion? https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try: https://bitbucket.org/emacsway/django-versioning. Django-versioning allows you to version the data stored in django models, and stores only diff, not content copy.
Supports all field types excepts ManyToMany (currently).

Maybe also useful for your project: the Django built-in comments app and the way of referring to objects. I think this is a nice and clean approach.

The physical database size doesn't matter. The number of records doesn't matter. See: [How big can a MySQL database get before performance starts to degrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276/how-big-can-a-mysql-database-get-before-performance-starts-to-degrade)

But how useful is it to keep a full history? You could start to delete history like TimeMachine does. Have daily (for a week), weekly (for some months) and monthly records. Crontab or Django-Celery help you to delete old history.

Comment: I knew django-versioning, but I found it with lack of documentation; Django comments is going to be [deprecated](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/HrWXBwe9BHU). database size does not matter, but table size does. Yes, I can start deleting history, that I will do for sure. Nevertheless, nice info, +1.

Comment: Ah, deprecated comments, thats new to me. Just to be clear: I don't advice to use dj comments, only to look at it and copy some design principles. I like the way comments refer to any object. Good luck, nice question.