# do database size affect insert time in mysql?

Tags: mysql, performance, logging

I want to log my users' logins
so I created a database like this :

```
CREATE TABLE `Login` (
    `UserId` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `Ip` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `Date` DATETIME NOT NULL
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

With no trigger. no key. no index.

Insertion code is :

```
INSERT INTO `Login` (`UserId`, `Ip`, `Date`) VALUES ({userId}, INET_ATON({userIp}), NOW());
```

With some calculation iI know it will get big. Does large data affect insertion time ? 
With large data I mean more than 3 million record.

Comment: I don't know it well enough to give an answer, but I was able to dig this up out of my [bookmarks](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22888/how-database-size-affects-performance-theory-vs-reality).

Comment: @McAdam331 i saw this. it says 'not a big consideration' well. i need some numbers. for example if insertion to an empty table take 10ms how much time it take to insert to a big table (>3m records)?

Comment: Well, if you want a specific number, I would write a small application with a 3mil loop to insert junk data, and then insert a new row to find out. I believe MySQL gives you the time required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use this previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276/how-big-can-a-mysql-database-get-before-performance-starts-to-degrade):

Quoted from the top answer:

> *The physical database size doesn't matter. The number of records don't matter.
>   In my experience the biggest problem that you are going to run in to is not size, but the number of queries you can handle at a time*

Comment: Which means that with the time, the size will affect performance, does not it?

Answer (score 1):

Lets use the MySQL site to answer this question http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html

Because you do not have indexes, you will not notice performance degradation with the size increment.

Comment: update refman link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-optimization.html