# How many rows can MySQL store?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

So I am a beginner and have just learned MySQL by myself for a few months. I always use phpMyAdmin in my work. My past work only involved tables with about 100k rows so there is no major issue.

However my client now wants to store about 8 million rows in a table. Is it too much for MySQL/phpMyAdmin to store and handle?

Thanks very much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276/how-big-can-a-mysql-database-get-before-performance-starts-to-degrade

Comment: Depends on the machine used for the sever (as in how much space it has), for mysql itself yeah it can handle that much.

Comment: No. Tables with billions of rows are not unheard of. Just make sure you use good design principles and proper indexes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just Google it:

> In InnoDB, with a limit on table size of 64 terabytes and a MySQL row-size limit of 65,535 there can be 1,073,741,824 rows. That would be minimum number of records utilizing maximum row-size limit. However, more records can be added if the row size is smaller

This is what it says.

> **So as the answer there can be 1,073,741,824 rows.**

Answer (score 4):

We don't know how big or small of your record. Short records can  few integer fields or our records might be really big with hundreds of text or varchar fields. So measure of file size is the best way . This [Officilal Information](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-size-limit.html) may help you

[image]