# Can MySQL handle millions of users for my social networking app? MySQL Vs Other Database technologies?

Tags: php, android, mysql, database

We are developing a social networking app.

**Following are the features :**

1) Video/Photo sharing

2) Ranking / Complex Algorithms

3) Suggesions

4) Other features similiar to Instagram/Facebook

**Platforms :**

1) Front End - XML + Java (Android)

2) Backend - PHP + MySQL + Apache + Linux (LAMP stack)

**Questions :**

1) If my app gets 1 Million downloads in a week. Can MySQL handle such huge data?

2) If it can handle, how may concurrent users can it handle at a time without performance issue? Maximum users that MySQL can handle?

3) Any other databases can handle better ?

4) After reaching how many users, I should migrate for other better databases like Mango DB, Cassandra etc..,

My question is only on database technology. Assume that we have provided required server hardware for handling huge data. Also assume that we have optimized Database design with the best quality of coding.

Comment: Way too many unknowns to answer your question realistically. The basic answer is "Yes". But reality is that it depends on a lot of factors: Server hardware, network, clustering, quality of coding, quality of db design. Get everything right, and you can handle almost any amount of traffic. Mess just one thing up, and molasses will look like a speed demon.

Comment: My question is only on database technology. Assume that we have provided required server hardware for handling huge data. Also assume that we have optimized DB design with the best quality of coding

Answer (score 0):

This question may already answered here in some content. Follow this link : 
[How big can a MySQL database get before performance starts to degrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276/how-big-can-a-mysql-database-get-before-performance-starts-to-degrade)