# High performance database in Hibernate spring 3

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, sqlite

I am working on choosing the light weight database that should be suitable for Hibernate + Spring.

My use case is for storing 10 GB of data once and used for read-only purpose.

Initially I have chosen SQLite but it failed in Multi threaded environment.

Please suggest the right database

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

MySQL would be great choice.

Refer below good answers on capabilities of MySQL.

[How big can a MySQL database get before performance starts to degrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276/how-big-can-a-mysql-database-get-before-performance-starts-to-degrade)