# How to model a relational database that stores order details?

Tags: android, sqlite, database-design, android-room

I am making a restaurant POS app for android and I am trying to decide the best way to model the database for it using Room ORM that ensures maintainability. My database needs, among a lot of other things, to keep a record of all items sold within a transaction/order, as well as a log of the orders themselves and a list of the food products sold within the restaurant.
Considering the following tables (for brevity purposes I only include columns I think relevant to the question and may not illustrate all the information I will need to catalog), I can create a table that includes a log of all the orders ever placed and call it all_orders:

```
all_orders
-----------
id (PK)
oder_details_id (FK) - referencing the PK from order_details table
date
notes
total
payment_type
```

I can also create a table that contains all the food products/dishes that the restaurant serves, and we’ll call it all_items:

```
all_items
---------
id (PK)
name
category
price
```

No problems there so far, but my current confusion lies here—**how do I manage to keep a log of the actual food items sold within an order?** 
One approach I thought about was to create a table per order number, but creating tables dynamically is already a problem and having 60,000 tables at the end of the year will be a maintainability nightmare. 
So my other possible solution is to create a table called order_details that will probably end up with hundreds of thousands of entries per year with the following columns:

```
order_details
-------------
id (PK)
item_id (FK) - referencing the PK from the all_items table
order_id (FK) - referencing the PK from the all_orders table
quantity_ordered
```

And when a user wants to pull up an order from say, last week, the program can use a join query that will produce the following to be displayed in the app’s UI:

```
order
---------
id (PK)
date (from the all_orders table)
name (from all_items)
category (from all_items)
price (from all_items)
total (from all_orders)
payment_type (from all_orders)
```

I am afraid that the **order_details table** is just too broad since it will contain hundreds of thousands of entries, and querying it for entries will be sluggish. I'm sure indexing it will help, but is this the correct approach to this problem? If not, **is there a better, “best practice” solution? If possible something that focuses on grouping any order and its items together without just dumping all items from all orders into one table**. Any help will be most appreciated.

Edit: This question is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1276/11536446), and while helpful, the supplied link has not provided any additional context on what I am really asking about nor is it entirely relevant to the answer I am after. I have bolded my last original paragraph since my question is really about a how I can model the above data as it isn't clear to me based on my research **how to store actual order details attached to an order** (many tutorials/similar questions I've come across fail short of thoroughly explaining the aforementioned).

Comment: There is no point in worrying re things you notice when you are uninformed/inexperienced or re optimizing straightforward designs before a demonstrated inadequacy. This sort of thing is what relational DBMSs are for. Time to read a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not textbooks on doing information modeling & database design.) Then on SQL DB optimization. PS We usually record details as invoiced regardless of current state. Research POS schemas & temporalDBs. Also partitioning.

Comment: (Obviously--) This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. (Eg google things like, 'site:stackoverflow.com how do i design my database so that queries do not get too slow as the table grows' etc.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How big can a MySQL database get before performance starts to degrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276/how-big-can-a-mysql-database-get-before-performance-starts-to-degrade)

Comment: Unsure if you actually read my question thoroughly or if I wasn't clear enough, but this question isn't about performance (while it is a concern, it is not what I am asking about). I have added to the original question as well.

Comment: "*I am afraid that [...], and querying it for entries will be sluggish*. I'm sure indexing it will help, but is this the correct approach to this problem? If not, **is there a better, “best practice” solution?**" Performance. PS Your question still isn't very clear. But it is all about doing something to improve peformance for fear of bad performance. If you want to know about designs & performance is just your motivation, be clearer about what you want to know, give clear requirements & drop the motivation/performance part. PS Don't use bold. Write clearly.

Comment: My current generic comment re "better"/"best" etc: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless you define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **all_orders** table would be superfluous as that is just repeating other data and would be contrary to normalisation.

You probably want a category table rather than repeat data (i.e. normalise categories).

Likewise, you also probably want a payment_type table (again to normalise).

Creating individual tables for orders would probably just create a nightmare.

Price and total aren't they the same? Saying that totals can be derived when extracting the data so there is no need to store such information.

As such the following structure schema may be close to what you want :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS item;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS category;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS category (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, category_name TEXT);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS item (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    item_name TEXT UNIQUE, 
    category_ref INTEGER REFERENCES category(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
    item_price REAL
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS payment_type;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS payment_type (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    payment_type TEXT UNIQUE, 
    surcharge REAL
);

-- NOTE cannot call a table order as it is a keyword (not rea true but have to enclose the name e.g.g [order]). 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customer_order;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customer_order (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    customer_name TEXT, 
    date TEXT DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    payment_type_ref INTEGER REFERENCES payment_type(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS order_detail;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS order_detail (
    customer_order_ref INTEGER REFERENCES customer_order(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
    item_ref REFERENCES item(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    quantity
);
```

## Example

The following is native SQL that demonstrates the schema above :-

### Part 1 adding (inserting) the data :-

```
INSERT INTO category (category_name) VALUES
    ('Fish'),('Beef'),('Chicken'),('Lamb'),('Sea Food')
;
INSERT INTO item (item_name, item_price, category_ref) VALUES
    ('Fish and Chips',11.30,1),
    ('Steak and Kidney Pudding',15.45,2),
    ('Lamb Chops, Mashed Potato and Gravy',17.40,3)
;

INSERT INTO payment_type (payment_type, surcharge) VALUES
    ('Master Card',0.05),('Visa',0.05),('Cash',0),('American Express',0.15)
;

INSERT INTO customer_order (customer_name, payment_type_ref) VALUES
    ('Fred',3),
    ('Mary',1),
    ('Tom',2),
    ('Jane',4)
;
INSERT INTO order_detail (customer_order_ref, item_ref, quantity) VALUES
    (1,1,2),(1,2,1), -- Fred (id 1) orders 2 Fish and Chips (id 1) and 1 Steak and Kidney (id 2)
    (2,3,10), -- Mary orders 10 Lamb chops
    (3,2,1),(3,1,1),(3,3,1), -- Tom orders 1 of each
  (4,1,1) -- Just Fish and chips for Jane   
;
```

### Part 2 - Extracting Useful(*perhaps*) Data

Here's and example of what you can do with SQL which includes derived data (*as suggested above*) :-

```
SELECT 
    customer_name, 
    date, 
    group_concat(item_name) ||'('||quantity||')' AS items, 
    sum(item_price) AS total_price, 
    payment_type, 
    round(sum(item_price) * surcharge,2) AS surcharge,
    round((sum(item_price) * surcharge) + sum(item_price),2) AS total_price
    FROM customer_order
        JOIN order_detail ON customer_order._id = order_detail.customer_order_ref
        JOIN item ON order_detail.item_ref = item._id
        JOIN payment_type ON customer_order.payment_type_ref = payment_type._id
    GROUP BY customer_order._id -- Treats all data for an order as a single row allowing the use of aggregate functions on the groups e.g. sum, group_concat
;
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: @ElizabethSinclair if it weren't room I would have created (was creating till I realised it was room) the demo on Android. As it is you'll have to mess around with the Entities etc.

Comment: No worries! Fortunately, I am confident I can properly translate this into Room as I've been working with it for a while.